# Anonymous access in cross-site publishing scenario leads to login prompt (401)

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, cross-site-publishing

I have published a pages library via cross-site publishing. The catalog was published with the "Allow anonymous access" setting enabled. In a separate public-facing web application there is a publishing site collection that integrates the published catalog.  This web application as well as the publishing site collection both have anonymous access enabled. Integrating the catalog automatically yields a term-based navigation which gets displayed as it should.

For authenticated users everything works fine. An anonymous user can still access the root web of the publishing site collection. However, if he clicks on any of the navigation links, a popup appears prompting the user to log in. If the login is cancelled a blank page appears with the text "401 unauthorized".

Can anyone tell me why the user is still prompted to login? What do I have to do to allow users to access the published catalog content?

Comment: Did you make sure target page is published and has anonymous access?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your urls aren't being rewritten. When you connected the remote list to your publishing site did you tick the box to "Make URLs relative to this site"?

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTVW5fqafy4) around 49:45 talks about it.

Anonymous access only grants the search index the ability to share the content without requiring security checks. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTVW5fqafy4) has more about it around 27:20 or so.